# How to get value of a string for a db.transaction

Tags: javascript, database, string, sqlite, dynamic

I'm stuck on a problem that should not be a problem ...

Code: the transaction

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(insertStatementElement, [values], doNothing, onError);
});
```

Example for values:

`["000096", "The Gold Medal Collection", "Harry Chapin", "Elektra", "140", "AAD", "Rock",         "AA8", "32", "2", "7.78", "22.48"]`

```
var insertStatementElement = 
   "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Menu" + counter + "
     (CDNUMBER, TITLE, ARTIST, LABEL, PLAYINGTIME, RECORDINGTYPE, MUSICTYPE, BINLOCATION, NUMBEROFTRACKS, ONHAND, COST, RETAIL) 
     VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

i got an error that the number of '?' in the sql statement does not match.

*EDIT*: If i do this change on my code...

```
var insertStatementElement = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Menu" + ebenecounter + " (CDNUMBER) VALUES (?)"
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(insertStatementElement, [values], doNothing, onError);
});
```

I get this result

[image: Table example]

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the [] characters around [values], so the line reads:

```
tx.executeSql(insertStatementElement, values, doNothing, onError);
```

Comment: I got this error:"Uncaught Error: TypeMismatchError: DOM Exception 17" if i remove the [].